# How do I properly write an ARM template for topic and subscription

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager

I have the following code:

```
// Create event topics and listeners
    {
        "comments": "Service Bus Topic - clusterprocessingcompletedevent",
        "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics",
        "name": "[concat(variables('resource_names').service_bus_namespaces.core, '/clusterprocessingcompletedevent')]",
        "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', variables('resource_names').service_bus_namespaces.core)]"
        ],
        "resources": [
            {
                "comments": "Service Bus Topic Subscription - notification.clusterprocessingcompletedevent",
                "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
                "name": "[concat(variables('resource_names').service_bus_namespaces.core, '/clusterprocessingcompletedevent', '/notification.clusterprocessingcompletedevent')]",
                "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics', variables('resource_names').service_bus_namespaces.core, '/clusterprocessingcompletedevent')]"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

When trying to use it, I get this error:

> Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': function
>   requires exactly one multi-segmented argument which must be resource
>   type including resource provider namespace

How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-resource-manager-namespace-topic?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes, I did take a look at it. If it's possible, I don't want to define a parameter 'serviceBusTopicName'. Any way I can avoid doing that? The 'dependsOn' parameter in the subscription resource seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be the issue:

```
"dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics', variables('resource_names').service_bus_namespaces.core, 'clusterprocessingcompletedevent')]"
]
```

so you have an extra `/` in the topic name. the same should apply to this: `variables('resource_names').service_bus_namespaces.core`. It should be a name of the namespace, without `/` in it.